# How to combine a <div> with a Rails "link_to"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a "to-do website". Users can log in and generate tasks as well as notes. The tasks work perfectly but I have some issues with notes for some reason. I don't use any partials for notes. If I use this on my **index.html.erb** as I did for the tasks:

```
<div class="notes">
<%= link_to 'New Note', new_note_path %>

 <div class="note">
    <div>
    <%= link_to note_path(note) do %>
      <%= note.content %>
    <%= link_to 'X', note, :class => 'task-destroy', method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
    <% end %>
    </div>

    <div>
    <%= link_to edit_note_path(note) do %>
      <%= time_ago_in_words(note.updated_at) %> ago
    <% end %>
    </div>
 </div>  
</div>
```

**I get:**

> "NameError in NotesController#index" - "undefined local variable or
>   method `note' for #..."

**notes_controller.rb**

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
before_action :logged_in_user
before_action :set_note, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
 @notes = current_user.notes
end

def show
end

def new
 @note = Note.new
end

def edit
end

def create
 @note = current_user.notes.new(note_params)
 if @note.save
  flash[:success] = "You successfully created a Note!"
  redirect_to notes_path
 else
  render 'new_note_path'
 end
end

def update
 @note.update(note_params)
 if @note.save
  flash[:success] = "You successfully updated a Note!"
  redirect_to notes_path
 else
  render 'edit_note_path'
 end
end

def destroy
 @note.destroy
  flash[:success] = "You successfully deleted a Note!"
  redirect_to notes_path
end

private

 def set_note
   @note = Note.find(params[:id])
 end

 def note_params
   params.require(:note).permit(:content)
 end
end
```

**Question:** What is wrong with my instance variable on my controller and how can I make it work?

Comment: On what line do you get that error? What is the exact error message? What object does not respond to `note`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add loop before `<div class="note">` to loop through list of notes stored in `@notes` in your index action.

Html should look like this:

```
<% @notes.each do |note| %>
<div class="note">
    <div>
    <%= link_to note_path(note) do %>
      <%= note.content %>
    <%= link_to 'X', note, :class => 'task-destroy', method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
    <% end %>
    </div>

    <div>
    <%= link_to edit_note_path(note) do %>
      <%= time_ago_in_words(note.updated_at) %> ago
    <% end %>
    </div>
 </div>  
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `index.html.erb` view doesn't have access to a `note` variable.

The instance variable from the following method is the only variable being passed to the view:

```
def index
 @notes = current_user.notes
end
```

You would probably need to do something like,

```
<% @notes.each do |n| >
<%= link_to(n) >
<% end >
```